# How to get the largest and shortest name from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to get the longest and shortest name from a file and print it out. If two people's names are the same length and are the biggest/smallest I also need to print that out.

**What I tried:**

```py
try:
    marvel_number = 0
    with open("Marvel.txt") as numbers_file:
        for line in numbers_file:
            marvel_number = marvel_number + 1
            print(len(marvel_number))
```

When I ran this code it gave me this error:

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

This is the Marvel.txt file which I am trying to read from
[image: This is the Marvel.txt file which I am trying to read from]

Comment: As I see from the code mentioned above, you are trying to get the length of int which declared at the top(marvel_number = 0). The error clearly says that you cannot use len() for int type. Can you please elaborate on what you are trying here? I would definitely be happy to help you to solve the issue :)

Comment: What your code does (apart from the print) is count the number of lines in the file. 

Can you supply an example of the contents of the file? Is it a list of names? Is it a list of numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over all these names in the file, store them in a list called `names` and then sort that list based on each item's length. By default, Python's order is ascending, so the shortest name is the first element and the longest name is the last element:

```
with open('marvel.txt', 'r') as numbers_file:
    names = sorted([line.strip() for line in numbers_file], key=len)
    print('Shortest name: ' + names[0])
    print('Longest name: ' + names[-1])
```

This will print:

```
Shortest name: Thanos
Longest name: Black Widow
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will identify the longest line in the numbers_file, and print it.

```
try:
    longest_name = ''
    with open("Marvel.txt") as numbers_file:
        for line in numbers_file:
            if len(line) > len(longest_name):
                longest_name = line
        print(longest_name)
```

Comment: This works thanks, however what can I do for the shortest name? I tired changing the ">" in the if statement to a "<" but I was not getting any output as a result.

Comment: @Wawapython123 for the shortest name you have to initialize `longest_name` with a very long string (e.g. 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'). It can be anything because it will be replaced by a shorter name. Changing `>` to `<` was the right thing to do. But it can't find a string shorter than an empty string.